# Declare a BIT variable and set it as a Subquery in SQL Oracle Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, boolean, subquery

I am using Oracle SQL Developer and I am trying to set a boolean variable to the result of a subquery. However I am getting a syntax error saying that I am missing the ":". I tried to insert the colon pretty much everywhere in my code but it doesn't seem to work. Any Ideas?

```
DECLARE @HasntPassedCourse BIT;
SET @HasntPassedCourse = 
EXISTS 
(SELECT P.cid, P.code
FROM PassedCourses P
WHERE P.code != :newline.code AND P.cid != :newline.cid);
```

Comment: You can't have an unquoted identifier starting with @ in Oracle; are you running this against an Oracle DB, or just using SQL Developer to connect to a different RDBMS? What is the whole error message you get?

Comment: This surely can't be oracle. `DECLARE variable BIT;` Oracle would probably say something like invalid plsql block, because of the `DECLARE`.

Comment: I think you want `DECLARE HasntPassedCourse BOOLEAN;`

Comment: @ruudvan, what is invalid about starting a PL/SQL block with `DECLARE`?

Comment: @DavidFaber, not the DECLARE itself but the fact that a DECLARE doesnt have a BEGIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like the following. First, Oracle doesn't allow `@` signs for variable names. It also doesn't have a `BIT` datatype (although PL/SQL will allow a `BOOLEAN`). You also can't insert a column value of any type into a `BOOLEAN` variable.

```
DECLARE
  HasntPassedCourse BOOLEAN;
  v_cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
  HasntPassedCourse := FALSE;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_cnt FROM dual;
  IF v_cnt != 0 THEN
    HasntPassedCourse := TRUE;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Personally, I think you're better off just using the # of rows returned in the query, and leaving `0` to indicate `FALSE`:

```
DECLARE
  HasntPassedCourse NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO HasntPassedCourse FROM <your query here>;
END;
/
```

If you want just zeroes and ones, then add `AND rownum = 1` to your query. So you might do something like the following:

```
DECLARE
  HasntPassedCourse NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO HasntPassedCourse FROM PassedCourses P
   WHERE P.code != :newline.code AND P.cid != :newline.cid
     AND rownum = 1;
END;
/
```

I assume `:newline` is a reference to a row added or updated via a trigger?